# how to print out snippets of a RDD in the spark-shell / pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When working in the spark-shell, I frequently want to inspect RDDs (similar to using `head` in unix).

For example:

```
scala> val readmeFile = sc.textFile("input/tmp/README.md")
scala> // how to inspect the readmeFile?
```

and ...

```
scala> val linesContainingSpark = readmeFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark"))
scala> // how to inspect linesContainingSpark?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found out how to do this ([here](https://bigdatauniversity.com/courses/introduction-to-scala/)) and thought this will be useful for other users, so sharing here.  `take(x)` selects the first x items and foreach prints them:

```
scala> val readmeFile = sc.textFile("input/tmp/README.md")
scala> readmeFile.take(5).foreach(println)
# Apache Spark

Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides
high-level APIs in Scala, Java, and Python, and an optimized engine that
supports general computation graphs for data analysis. It also supports a
```

and ...

```
scala> val linesContainingSpark = readmeFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark"))
scala> linesContainingSpark.take(5).foreach(println)
# Apache Spark
Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides
rich set of higher-level tools including Spark SQL for SQL and structured
and Spark Streaming.
You can find the latest Spark documentation, including a programming
```

---

The examples below are the equivalent but using pyspark:

```
>>> readmeFile = sc.textFile("input/tmp/README.md")
>>> for line in readmeFile.take(5): print line
... 
# Apache Spark

Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides
high-level APIs in Scala, Java, and Python, and an optimized engine that
supports general computation graphs for data analysis. It also supports a
```

and

```
>>> linesContainingSpark = readmeFile.filter(lambda line: "Spark" in line)
>>> for line in linesContainingSpark.take(5): print line
... 
# Apache Spark
Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides
rich set of higher-level tools including Spark SQL for SQL and structured
and Spark Streaming.
You can find the latest Spark documentation, including a programming
```

Comment: Probably you've realized already; the `take(5)` would be indeed like `head` in unix, and the `filter` you were using in your posted question would be more like a `grep`. However, the `filter` did not give you any results just like that since you did not collect them; the easiest way would be adding a `take` after the `filter`.